# asp.net IScriptControl $create order

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, scriptmanager

I have two script controls (code is very simplified):

```
class Form : IScriptControl
{
      Panel pnl;
      Button trigger;
      public Form()
      {
           pnl = new Panel();
           trigger = new Button();

           IPresenter p = new Popup();
           p.SetContent(this.pnl);           
           this.Controls.Add(trigger);
      }
}

class Popup : IScriptControl, IPresenter
{
      public void SetContent(Control content)
      {
           this.Controls.Add(content);
      }
}
```

Now in the HTML output, i see the following (again very simplified):

```
<div id="ctrlForm">
    <div id="ctrlPopup">
        <div id="ctrlFormPnl"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="ctrlFormTrigger"></div>
</div>
```

And script:

```
Sys.Application.add_init(function() {
    $create(Form, {"_presenter":"FormPresenter"}, null, null, $get("ctrlForm"));
});
Sys.Application.add_init(function() {
    $create(Popup, {"_isOpen":false}, null, null, $get("ctrlPopup"));
});
```

Question: How I can do, that the script that creates the popup appears on page before script of form...in other words, when initializer of the ctrlForm control executes, I want to get reference to forms presenter.

I hope I clearly explained what I want to do. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In order to archive you goal you should let the child controls to register with ScriptManager  **before** your control.

This can be done if you register your control with ScriptManager inside overridden Render method, **after** calling base.Render(...)
like that:

```
    protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        // Let child controls to register with ScriptManager
        base.Render(writer);

        // Now, when all the nested controls have been registered with ScriptManager
        // We register our control.
        // This way $create statement for this control will be rendered
        // AFTER the child controls' $create 
        if (this.DesignMode == false)
        {
            ScriptManager sm = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this.Page);
            if (sm != null)
                sm.RegisterScriptDescriptors(this);
        }

   }
```